# How to Block normal user access to mysql

Tags: mysql

user can access mysql by command mysql.
I want to change it so that only root users can run mysql.

ex) mysql // denied
ex) mysql -u root // access

Comment: To do so you need to write your own `mysql` client program...

Answer (score 0):

Question need more info.

Unless we set .my.cnf (mysql clinet) on the server, No one can access by mysql simply by hitting mysql, Else you need do mysql_secure_installation to set mysql root password if you haven't done it before.